# Connecting Digital Persona U are U Fingerprint Reader

Tags: android, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I'm currently creating an Attendance Monitoring as my Final requirement to graduate this year. I using Digital Persona you are you 4500 Fingerprint Reader and I want to connect it in Android Studio. With used of Fingerprint Reader the students will easily register with their fingerprint in my application.

My problem is how can I connect the Fingerprint Reader in Android Studio and how can I use it to register and verify the fingerprint?

Comment: ok .. but can you tell me if how can i connect it?

Comment: That's a question for the fingerprint reader manufacturer, not for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but using Xamarin. I'm sorry, but you cannot connect a digital persona to an emulator. Instead, debug via an android device that supports OTG